Strange consequence of linear combination of normal distribution
I have trouble with a consequence of this theorem

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent normal distributions with expected value $\mu _i$ and variance $\sigma _i ^2$. Then the random variable $Y = \sum _{i=1} ^{n} \alpha_i X_i$ (which is a linear combination of normal distributions with $\alpha _i \in \mathbb{R}$) is a normal distribution with expected value $\mu = \sum _{i=1} ^{n} \alpha_i \mu _i$ and variance $\sigma ^2 = \sum _{i=1} ^{n} \alpha _i ^2 \sigma _i ^2$.

This seems to have, as consequence, that $W = Y+Y$ isn't equal to $U = 2Y$, which seems strange to me. For example, if $Y$ has $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma= 1$, then $U=2Y$ has $\mu _U = 0 \times 2 = 0$ and $\sigma _U= 2^2 \times 1 = 4$. Meanwhile $W=Y+Y$ has $\mu _W = 0 + 0 = 0$ and $\sigma _W= 1 \times 1^2 + 1 \times 1^2 = 2$. Is this correct even though it's strange or am I missing something?

Your theorem  is very wrong. The conclusion holds only under the assumption of independence of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$. You should always pay attention  to independence hypothesis.

@geetha290krm thanks, just forgot to write it, but it wasn't what my question was about. I'm interested in what I've written after the theorem, could you please help me?

You have added "independent" to your claim.  But then the $Y+Y$ in your question is confusing.
If $Y_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and independently $Y_2 \sim N(0,1)$ then $U=Y_1+Y_1=2Y_1 \sim N(0,4)$ while $W=Y_1+Y_2 \sim N(0,2)$ and they are different.
$U$ having a larger variance than $W$ should be no surprise: $Y_1$ is positively correlated with itself but not with $Y_2$.

Of course! Such a stupid mistake. Thanks

The result is true only when the random variables are independent.The proof is simple. Without the assumption of independence, it is clearly false. A simple counter-example is $U = Y-Y = 0$ which is not gaussian even if $Y$ is gaussian.

Arguably your $U \sim N(0,0)$ as an edge case (as you would get in the original claim if all the $\alpha_i =0)$

thanks, just forgot to write it, but it wasn't what my question was about. I'm interested in what I've written after the theorem, could you please help me?

Yes, what you've written after the theorem is wrong because the theorem is wrong :)
